# Creating an installer file for Internet Explorer/Firefox/Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, installation

I'm making a CD catalog for distrobution, and in order to properly view the Catalog the end user needs to have a web browser. I know it seems basic, but my boss assured me that many of the clients who will be looking at the Catalog wont have a web browser.

I've done a bit of searching, and found only two articles that mention anything like this (though since I'm pretty ignorant to terminology, I'm probably looking in all the wrong places). I tried the first article but couldnt follow the directions because of how vague they were, and the second article was about creating a batch file, which I've never done, but it was for German Explorer anyway, and these clients are American heh.

So my question is, how can I create/acquire an installer file for Explorer (preferably all 3 browsers but if only IE is available thats perfect. My boss prefers IE)? If I have to make one then please be as detailed with descriptions as possible. Im not a programmer by any means, though I've been doing a lot of programming lately it seems, so I'm still in the process of learning.

I apologize if this isnt the correct place to post a question like this, but I saw someone mention this before here (the person didnt speak good english, so I was quite confused by the end of it heh), so hopefully I'm not too far off in coming here for help. Thanks and appologies in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer.

Basically I went to the IE download page, and when prompted to Run, Save, or Cancel I chose 'Save' then opened the folder when it was done, and the .exe file for IE was there. Did the same with Firefox as well. Unfortunately Google goes right into the download without a prompt, so I couldnt do this with Chrome.